# Captcha in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, captcha

I am developing a website where I need a captcha control and I want to develop the captcha control itself, so in the future I can change its length, type, color, and have it be easy to manage as well.

So, suggest me which technology used for to develop the capha control and how.

I am using asp.net platform with vb.net as the language.

Comment: Why would you want to change its length, type and colour? Can you not just use [ReCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)?

Comment: Write your own, only if it is absolutely critical. Your requirement doesn't sound critical.

Comment: Too bad [hotcaptcha](http://gizmodo.com/#!187781/hotcaptcha-hot-babes-eliminate-bots) is no longer around...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [reCAPTCHA](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.html).

Comment: Thank you for this, but what i do if i want to made own captcha control.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this (free): http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/an-aspnet-captcha-server-control.html

Or Telerik has a great Captcha product (not free).

Comment: +1 for Jeff Atwood's Captcha.  It's an oldie but goodie.  We are happily using it on an intranet site for some time now.

Answer (score 0):

BotDetect CAPTCHA is excellent. I just used it on a big project. http://captcha.biz/

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of existing options you could use (as others have pointed out).  But, if you want to roll your own, you might want to consider WPF/Silverlight.  There are a lot tools in there to manipulate/transform letters and numbers that you could utilize.

You could apply a random (or several random) transformations to each letter/number of a randomly generated string of letters/numbers.